# How to read Energy meter readings over serial port using COM port?

Tags: serial-port, master-slave, modbus, usbserial, energy

I have interfaced my Energy Meter with RS232, and then used a RS232-to-USB-Cable to interface with my PC. My Energy Meter uses Modbus Protocol.

I get readings like these through Modbus Slave / Modbus Poll software. How do I get it in the right format?

000024-Rx:AB 26 EA 59 94 FD B2 65 90 65 E4 AB 26 1D CA BA FE 57 8A 55 CA 55 FF

000025-Rx:AB 26 EA 59 94 FD B2 65 90 65 E4 AB 26 1D CA BA FC D7 8A 55 8A 55 FF

000026-Rx:AB 26 EA 59 94 FD B2 65 90 65 A4 AB A6 EB B2 AE FA 57 CA 55 CA 55 FF

000027-Rx:AB 26 EA 59 94 FD B2 65 90 65 A4 AB A6 EB B2 AE FA 57 CA 55 CA 55 FF

.

.

000040-Rx:AB 26 EA D6 EB FF B2 65 94 65 C6 AB 26 EB B2 AE FA 55 8A D5 8A 55 FF

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" about what you showed. Perhaps you should read the manual for your software and learn more about the Modbus protocol. Then armed with that info, you can ask a better question.

Comment: @iheanyi , I have read the complete operating manual for the instrument. There is nothing enclosed anywhere as to how to convert these values and get appropriate meter readings. I am a noob for modbus protocols. Do help me to decode these values.

Comment: Modbus defines the overall protocol and command/response format, but your specific device defines the specific registers referenced and their specific content. So, the decoding of this data is specific to your actual meter, which you haven't named. You need to find the protocol specification for *your* meter. Think of modbus as equivalent to the http protocol and your meter as equivalent to a web server. A web server can implement whatever page structure it wants, and this all works within the http protocol. That's how modbus and your meter work together.

Comment: If you want someone to turn those Modbus messages into something else - which you've not even mentioned what it should be, you can advertise for a job and pay someone. If you want help - I've given it, namely, I've pointed you in the direction of things you need to read (software manual, Modbus protocol description) to solve your problem. Doing the work for you is not helping you, it's working for you.

Comment: @barny , My Energy Meter is RISH EM 1330 : http://www.rishabh.co.in/index.php/products/product/253     And the Datasheet for the same is here: http://www.rishabh.co.in/uploads/product/Rish_EM_13xx.pdf . As mentioned in the question, I am getting those kind of readings over Modbus Poll Software. I want readings like 240V voltage, 220 mA Current, power factor 1, etc.  I tried checking them in float/ int / double / etc. But I am unable to get the readings yet. All I know is the Energy meter uses a Modbus Protocol to communicate. I am a noob to Modbus, so bear with me, and help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn how to footle around on manufacturer websites to find any information which might be even close to what you need. There is a mod bus protocol manual for your meter if you go to Support->Downloads, put a check mark against just Multifunction Meters, and on the listing row RISH EM 1320/30/40 click the right hand link in the column Manuals.

The manual is here: http://www.rishabh.co.in/index.php/products/download/349

That manual seems to give the register addresses you should look at for different values. I obviously can't know what your modbus polling software is actually doing to get the data you posted, you need to make it look at the modbus registers that have the data you are interested in using the manual as a guide. No I don't know any more about your particular meter.

BTW if you had actually tried I'm sure you could have found this yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Got it.